# Timestampable Trait of Gedmo Doctrine extension throws error

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I got the following entity

```
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * Hook timestampable behavior
     * updates createdAt, updatedAt fields
     */
    use TimestampableEntity;
```

...

if i run

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

i get this error

```
found 8 mapped entities:
[OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation
[OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation
[OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation
[OK]   Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry
[OK]   Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry
[OK]   Gedmo\Tree\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractClosure
[OK]   Psren\CmsBundle\Entity\Group



  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                                                                    
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Gedmo\Timestampable" in property Psren\CmsBundle\Entity\User::$createdAt was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

the annotation @Gedmo\Timestampable was defined in the trait of the extension. so it must have been loaded.

what went wrong?
thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:-)

I just fortgot to load the annotations.

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * Hook timestampable behavior
     * updates createdAt, updatedAt fields
     */
    use TimestampableEntity;
```